# Openlayers doesn't want to show map throught Mapserver

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver

I have a configured Mapserver with WMS service, I know Its working because I tried in QGIS and I can see the map. The problem is that openlayers doesnt want to show the map via mapserver service. Yes, the projection is same...[image]

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>MapServer WMS OpenLayersben</title>
  <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script>
   function init()
   {

     var map = new OpenLayers.Map('terkep', 
      {
        projection: "EPSG:4326", 
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(19.64, 46.12, 20.77, 46.80), 
        maxResolution: 1000, 
        units: "m"
      } );

     var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "MapServer mintatérkép",
         'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/map.map', 
         {
           layers: ['Csongutak'], 
           format: 'image/png'
         },
         { singleTile: true });

     map.addLayer(wms);

     map.zoomToMaxExtent();
   } 
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="init()">
  <h1>MapServer WMS OpenLayersben</h1>
  <div id="terkep" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

mapserv file:

```
MAP
  NAME "MAPSERVER QUICKSTART"
  EXTENT 19.64 46.12 20.77 46.80
  UNITS dd
  SHAPEPATH "/home/"
  SIZE 1024 768

  IMAGETYPE PNG24

  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END

  WEB
    METADATA
      ows_enable_request "*"
    END
  END

  LAYER
    NAME "Csongradutak"
    STATUS ON
    TYPE LINE
    DATA "csong_utak"
    CLASS
      STYLE
        COLOR 0 0 0
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
      END
    END
  END
```

Comment: This could be a problem with path to directory where mapserver stores generates images. Do a right click and "inspect element" on the pink image. See what is the url and if it matches the actual directory.

Comment: I got this: `http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/map.map&LAYERS=Csongutak&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=6.47208984375,37.3047265625,33.93791015625,55.6152734375`
In the mapserver file I have fully enabled wms service:
`ows_enable_request "*"`

Comment: @afaf12 what do you think?

Comment: Do you get a map if you send that request (http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/map.map&LAYERS=Csongutak&FORMAT=‌​image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX‌​=6.47208984375,37.3047265625,33.93791015625,55.6152734375&) to your service.  If not what error do you get? Turn the debug level to 3 or 4 and look in the logs.

Comment: @nmtoken If I submit the link I can download a file (mapserv)...

Comment: But you should get a map on screen, not a downloadable file.  What does the file contents say or look like?  What do the logs say?

Comment: @nmtoken hmmm..something wrong
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
<ServiceException code="InvalidFormat">
msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): Image handling error. Unsupported output format ( ​image/png).
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
`

Comment: right click on a tile and do "Show Image" to have a clue of the error